# Return column with only number of characters

Tags: sql, db2

I have this query:

```
     SELECT GUITAR_NO,COUNT(INVENTORY)
     FROM INVENTORY.GUITARS
     WHERE guitars.guitar_type = 'FENDER' and GUITARS.Guitar_no LIKE('4%')
     GROUP BY GUITAR_NO
```

I'm trying to get the query to only return guitar characters that are 6 characters long, no longer no shorter. Is there a way to do this in DB2?

Bonus: How do I return only those guitar_no where Count(inventory) > 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `LENGTH` function that returns integer representation of what ever field you pass in.

In your `WHERE` clause just add `AND LENGTH(GuitarName) = 6` just replace `GuitarName` with your field that you need to check.

to get rid of extra white space just wrap it in `TRIM` function

`LENGTH(TRIM(GuitarName)) = 6`

Bonus:

Just add `HAVING` Clause after `GROUP BY`

```
 SELECT GUITAR_NO,COUNT(INVENTORY)
 FROM INVENTORY.GUITARS
 WHERE guitars.guitar_type = 'FENDER' 
    and GUITARS.Guitar_no LIKE('4%') 
    and LENGTH(TRIM(guitars.guitar_type)) = 6 
 GROUP BY GUITAR_NO
 HAVING COUNT(INVENTORY) > 3
```

Comment: Can I do only characters, its picking up white spaces at the end.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `LENGTH(TRIM(guitar_type)) = 6` in your `WHERE` clause
2. Use `HAVING COUNT(INVENTORY) > 3` after your `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: the lenght is picking up white spaces at the end, can i limit it to only count letters?